# How to open a new timePicker displaying an old time in Android tablet

Tags: c#, android, datetimepicker

If I open a new timePicker, it usually displays the current time. 
I would like to display a specific time (say, 8:44:05) in the pop up timePicker. How can I do that? I would appreciate if anyone can help out.

Comment: Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html), specifically the setCurrentHour and setCurrentMinute methods, and give it a try. If you have trouble, post code and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the popup timepicker call, set the desired hourOfDay, and minute instead of using the current ones. use the following constructor

```
TimePickerDialog(Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
```